# Developing $f(z) = z^2 + z + 1$ in Taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis

How to develop in Taylor series
$f(z) = z^2 + z + 1, z \in \mathbb{C} $ around $z_{0} = 1$?

I'm begginer in studying complex analysis,  so any hint helps!

Comment: Hint: replace $z$ with $(z-z_0)+1$ and expand (keeping the $(z-z_0)^n$ terms unchanged).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I was thinking of that too but answer Minus One-Twelfth gave seems easier

Comment: A polynomial is its own series. Just express $f(z)$ as a polynomial in $z-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the formula for Taylor series: $$f(z)= f(1)+f'(1)(z-1)+\frac{1}{2}f''(1)(z-1)^2+\cdots.$$

You should be able to show that all higher derivatives (third derivative and higher) are in fact $0$.